# In Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz, why if (f == null) was checked twice in Memoizer

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz provides an example of a efficient scalable cache for concurrent use. The final version of the example showing the implementation for class Memoizer (pg 108) shows such a cache. I am wondering why there were an inner and outer check of the if (f == null). 
The second one does not make any sense because:

1. there is a check ahead and the immediate last step ahead will definitely return a not-null value out of cache.putIfAbsent(arg,
   ft);
2. the ft.run() inside the second check does not make any sense because f.get() will be called immediately thereafter.

Here is the code for Memoizer:

```
public class Memoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache
    = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
private final Computable<A, V> c;

public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }

public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
        if (f == null) {
            Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                public V call() throws InterruptedException {
                    return c.compute(arg);
                }
            };
            FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
            f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
            if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }
        }
        try {
            return f.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            cache.remove(arg, f);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. there is a check ahead and the immediate last step ahead will definitely return a not-null value out of `cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);`

If there is only a single thread calling `compute`, then `cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);` will *always* return `null`, as there is no previous value.

If there are two or more threads calling the `compute` method at the same time, then only one of them will get `null` out of `cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);`, the others will get the value of `ft` that the thread which got `null` created.

In that case, the other threads throw away their instance of FutureTask and continue with the instance that they received from `cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);`

> 2. the ft.run() inside the second check does not make any sense because f.get() will be called immediately thereafter.

You need to `run` a `FutureTask` in order to `get` the value from it later. If you don't call `run` you won't ever get a value. The thread that created the FutureTask that got stored in the cache, will `run` it and then `get` will return immediately, because it is already complete at that point.

But the other threads that called `compute` at the same time and that got a non-null value from `putIfAbsent`, will go to the `get` call and *wait* until the first thread is done with the `run` method.

Comment: thanks a lot. right to the point and precisely all the answers i need.